# Error al refrescar tabla en XHTML (Primefaces JavaWeb)

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo un problema al cargar una tabla desde una base de datos en MySQL. La tabla está en PrimeFaces y carga los datos de la base de datos cuando despliego la aplicación. Pero cuando modifico un dato, a pesar de que lo carga en la base de datos no lo muestra en la tabla.

#### Editado

Aquí algo del codigo.. no me funciona con la propiedad refrescar por medio del commandbutton ..

```
<p:panel id="tabla" style="width: 100% ; font-size: small; text-align: left ; border : none ;"  > 
    <p:dataTable style="border : none ;"
                 id="tablePro" var="programacion" value="#{mantenimientoTvista.listaProgramaciontodo}" rows="10"
                 paginator="true"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                 filteredValue="#{mantenimientoTvista.listaProgramaciontodo}"
                 emptyMessage="No se encontraron resultados"
                 selectionMode="single"
                 rowKey="#{programacion.idprogramacion}"
                 selection="#{mantenimientoTvista.programacionSeleccionado}"
                 >
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{mantenimientoTvista.funcionSeleccionarProd}" update="forma:growl ,:forma:campos" />

        <p:column headerText="nombre tecnico" width="30" filterBy="#{programacion.documentotecnico.personal.nombrepersonal}">
            <h:outputText value="#{programacion.documentotecnico.personal.nombrepersonal}"/>
        <p:column headerText="Tipo mant" width="5" filterBy="#{programacion.idclase.clasenombre}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{programacion.idclase.clasenombre}"/>
        </p:column>      
    </p:dataTable>

</p:panel>
```

y este es el boton dejo el codigo aqui aparte ----------------------------------------

y aqui el codigo del value de listaidtecnicos (omiti muchas columnas para no pegar un codigo demasiado extenso solo necesito que se refresque el nombre del tecnico cuando lo cambio en la tabla).

Esto es de clase entidad apartir de base de datos ..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personal")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personal.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Personal p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personal.findByDocumentopersonal", query = "SELECT p FROM Personal p WHERE p.documentopersonal = :documentopersonal"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personal.findByApellidopersonal", query = "SELECT p FROM Personal p WHERE p.apellidopersonal = :apellidopersonal"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personal.findByClavepersonal", query = "SELECT p FROM Personal p WHERE p.clavepersonal = :clavepersonal"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personal.findByNombrepersonal", query = "SELECT p FROM Personal p WHERE p.nombrepersonal = :nombrepersonal")})
public class Personal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "documentopersonal")
    private Long documentopersonal;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "apellidopersonal")
    private String apellidopersonal;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "clavepersonal")
    private String clavepersonal;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "nombrepersonal")
    private String nombrepersonal;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "personal")
    private Administrador administrador;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "personal")
    private Tecnicos tecnicos;

    public Personal() {
    }

    public Personal(Long documentopersonal) {
        this.documentopersonal = documentopersonal;
    }

    public Long getDocumentopersonal() {
        return documentopersonal;
    }

    public void setDocumentopersonal(Long documentopersonal) {
        this.documentopersonal = documentopersonal;
    }

    public String getApellidopersonal() {
        return apellidopersonal;
    }

    public void setApellidopersonal(String apellidopersonal) {
        this.apellidopersonal = apellidopersonal;
    }

    public String getClavepersonal() {
        return clavepersonal;
    }

    public void setClavepersonal(String clavepersonal) {
        this.clavepersonal = clavepersonal;
    }

    public String getNombrepersonal() {
        return nombrepersonal;
    }

    public void setNombrepersonal(String nombrepersonal) {
        this.nombrepersonal = nombrepersonal;
    }

    public Administrador getAdministrador() {
        return administrador;
    }

    public void setAdministrador(Administrador administrador) {
        this.administrador = administrador;
    }

    public Tecnicos getTecnicos() {
        return tecnicos;
    }

    public void setTecnicos(Tecnicos tecnicos) {
        this.tecnicos = tecnicos;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (documentopersonal != null ? documentopersonal.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Personal)) {
            return false;
        }
        Personal other = (Personal) object;
        if ((this.documentopersonal == null && other.documentopersonal != null) || (this.documentopersonal != null && !this.documentopersonal.equals(other.documentopersonal))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.simap.modelo.Personal[ documentopersonal=" + documentopersonal + " ]";
    }        

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Edwar. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código relevante para replicar tu problema.

Comment: No veo tu commandButton aún, que es posible sea allí en donde esté tu error.

Comment: Este es el boton .. ----                                                                                          <p: Unión commandButton action = "# {} mantenimientoTvista.funcionReasignarTecnico" id = "btnprocesar" value = "Modificar tecnico" icon = "ui-icono de disco" = "# {mantenimientoTvista .btnProcesar} "style =" margin-left: 46% "update =": forma: Campos ,: forma: gruñido ,: forma: tabla, forma: TablePro "/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un problema bastante frecuenta y molesto. Esto se llama `stale data`. Por lo general, ocurre cuando no estás operando dentro de una transacción y el EntityManager usa a una versión cacheada de la consulta. Tienes varias opciones.

### EntityManager#refresh

Llamando al método `refresh` de EntityManager refrescas el estado de la entidad, obligando a que se obtenga siempre la última versión del mismo.

```
em.refresh(objeto);
```

### EntityManagerFactory#getCache#evictAll

Otra opción es llamar al método `getCache()` del EntityManagerFactory y limpiar la cache mediante `evictAll()`, antes de obtener registros.

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```

#### Usar una transacción

Esto es lo más recomendado. No comentas si tienes un servidor full profile  o solo un contenedor de servlets como Tomcat o Jetty. Sin embargo, con ambos puedes realizar tus consultas en transacciones.

**Jetty o Tomcat**

```
EntityTransaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin(); // empiezas la transacción
    // tu lógica aquí
    tx.commit(); // finalizas la transacción
} catch (PersistenceException e) {
    // si algo sale mal, hacemos rollback para revertir cambios
    if(tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
       tx.rollback();
    }
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```

**WildFly, GlassFish, etc.**

En este tipo de servidores no necesitas lo anterior porque ya lo manejan ellos mediante JTA. Por ejemplo, tus servicios pueden ser **EJB's** que son transaccionales para hacer tu lógica.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UsuarioService implements Serializable {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   public List<Usuario> listar() {
       TypedQuery<Usuario> query = em.createNamedQuery(Usuario.FIND_ALL, Usuario.class);
       return query.getResultList();
   }
}
```

También puedes desactivar el caché de tu proveedor en el *persistence.xml*:

```
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</share-cache-mode>
```

Por el contrario, si lo que tienes es un problema de refrescar datos, fíjate que en el atributo `update` del `commandButton` estás poniendo un id válido. Recuerda que si *el elemento a actualizar está fuera del formulario*, debes de anteponer `:` al id. Por ejemplo:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{tuBean.metodo()}" update=":tabla" />
```

### Actualización

No he visto por ningún lado tu `commandButton`, lo que veo es un listener para selección de filas. En este listener tienes una coma (,) lo que no debería ir en versiones recientes de JSF. Puedes renderizar tantos elementos desees solo separándolos por espacios.

Comment: La explicación es buena, asumiendo que el OP trabaja con JPA.

Comment: Es lo que asumí, viendo que el OP usa Java EE xD

Answer (score 2):

Si utilizas un command button puedes asignarle la propiedad `update` al boton para que refresque la tabla de datos.

Ejemplo.

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{controlador.accion()}" 
                                                     update=":dataTableId"
                                                     icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s"
                                                     title="Cargar Datos">
                                        <f:param name="parametro1" value="valor1"/>
                                        <f:param name="parametro2" value="valor2"/> 
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que hago en estos casos es que cuando hago un cambio del dato, vuelvo a cargar la lista, y al listado resultante lo refresco con un método que agregué en el archivo AbstractFacade (yo trabajo con NetBeans y este lo crea automáticamente cuando se agregan los bean de sesión para las entidades), el código del método es el siguiente:

```
/**
 * Actualiza el listado cuando se ha hecho un cambio y no se refleja 
 * @param entityCollection
 * @return 
 */
public List<T> refreshCollection(List<T> entityCollection) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (entityCollection != null && !entityCollection.isEmpty()) {
        getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(entityCollection.get(0).getClass());
        T mergedEntity;
        for (T entity : entityCollection) {
            mergedEntity = getEntityManager().merge(entity);
            getEntityManager().refresh(mergedEntity);
            result.add(mergedEntity);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Entonces luego que cargo el listado, llamo ese método:

```
public List<Entidad> cargarDatos() {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT E FROM Entidad E");
    return refreshCollection(q.getResultList());
}
```

No hay que olvidar hacer un update al datatable para que se reflejen los cambios luego de haber actualizado la lista.
En general de esa forma soluciono ese problema.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Pues la solución que encontre ... no se por que , fue cambiar un campo de la tabla en la base de datos (En mi caso un AI ) para que me refrescara los datos en el xhtml aun no se por que, sigo buscando una solución mas practica y eficiente .